# Django class.object.all().aggregate(Max("foo")).get("foo__max") could not convert string to float

Tags: python, django

I have a setup on my local machine and on a development server.

On the local machine everything works as expected but on the development server I keep getting `Exception Value: could not convert string to float: SHC20160001`

Which of course makes sense because the string contains letters.

All I need is the maximum value that is currently in the table column, for which I use  `last_number = object_class.objects.all().aggregate(Max(number_field_name)).get("{}__max".format(number_field_name))`

The full function is:

```
def create_serial_number(object_instance):
    """
    Create serial number for e.g. order, shopping cart, invoice
    :param object_instance: The object the number should be generated for
    :type object_instance: object
    :return: Serial number
    """
    now = datetime.now()

    object_class, prefix, number_field_name = None, None, None
    if isinstance(object_instance, SalesOrder):
        object_class = SalesOrder
        number_field_name = "order_number"
        prefix = "ORD"
    elif isinstance(object_instance, ShoppingCart):
        object_class = ShoppingCart
        number_field_name = "shoppingcart_number"
        prefix = "SHC"

    assert object_class, "The object instance should have a proper value"

    # Check if the object already has a serial number
    current_value = getattr(object_instance, number_field_name)
    if current_value:
        return current_value

    # Get the date from the last number in the database for the object
    last_number = object_class.objects.all().aggregate(Max(number_field_name)).get("{}__max".format(number_field_name))
    # Return default value if there are no entries in the database yet
    if not last_number:
        return "{}{}{}".format(prefix, str(now.year), "0000")

    assert len(last_number) == 11, "The number should have a length of 11 characters"
    # Strip year from the number
    number_year = int(last_number[len(prefix):len(prefix) + 4])
    # Get the serial number from the last order number.
    serial_number = int(last_number[-4:])

    if number_year != now.year:
        year_string = str(now.year)
        serial_number = "0000"
    else:
        year_string = str(number_year)
        serial_number = str(serial_number + 1).zfill(4)

    return "{}{}{}".format(prefix, year_string, serial_number)
```

And the full traceback I get.

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  48.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  20.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/srv/www/development.content.skindustries.net-80/products/views.py" in dispatch
  75.         return super(SelectAdPositionView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  69.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/srv/www/development.content.skindustries.net-80/products/views.py" in post
  98.             return self.form_valid(form)
File "/srv/www/development.content.skindustries.net-80/products/views.py" in form_valid
  119.         shopping_cart = ShoppingCart.objects.get_or_create(user=user, company=company, status="OPEN")[0]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get_or_create
  134.         return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get_or_create
  452.                 obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File "/srv/www/development.content.skindustries.net-80/sales/models.py" in save
  175.         self.shoppingcart_number = create_serial_number(self)
File "/srv/www/development.content.skindustries.net-80/sales/models.py" in create_serial_number
  47.     last_number = object_class.objects.all().aggregate(Max(number_field_name)).get("{}__max".format(number_field_name))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in aggregate
  338.         return query.get_aggregation(using=self.db)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_aggregation
  391.             in zip(query.aggregate_select.items(), result)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in resolve_aggregate
  338.             return self.convert_values(value, aggregate.field, connection)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in convert_values
  316.         return connection.ops.convert_values(value, field)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py" in convert_values
  867.         return float(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /products/select-ad-position/182/
Exception Value: could not convert string to float: SHC20160001
```

I have been breaking my head over this, but I can't figure this out.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Could you please add the relevant models as well? It looks like one of your `number_field_name` is not really a number field.

Comment: you would need to add your model fields.

Comment: Which Python version you use on your local machine / development server?